# Find keyfile of an account

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, addresses, accounts, keystore

I have several accounts in my Geth wallet. I need to locate the keystore file of a given account but there doesn't seem to be any connection between the keystore file names and the accounts. How do I get the keystore file of a given account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generated the account with Geth, then the account is embedded in the name of the keystore file. As an example, take the following keystore file:

UTC--2017-10-18T01-34-15.931234561Z--bb22a1230f132a468c9383cabcabe00894aaa679

`UTC--2017-10-18T01-34-15.931234561Z` is the timestamp the keystore file was created.

`bb22a1230f132a468c9383cabcabe00894aaa679`is the address of the account. To search for it on a site like Etherscan, append `0x` to the beginning of the address.